# Items not getting deleted from realm

Tags: android, realm

```
io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.0'
Android Studio 2.2.2
```

I am trying to delete objects from the realm database. The items seems to get deleted. But when I close the app and load items from the database the deleted ones still seem to have a reference to them. This is my code below for deleting.

If the delete onSuccess is called I send back the item to be removed from the recyclerview's adapter. Is this the correct way to do this?

```
 @Override
    public void deletePerson(final Person person, final DeleteListener deleteListener) {
        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("mId", person.getId()).findAll();
                results.deleteAllFromRealm();
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                /* send the person object back to be removed from the recyclerview after success*/
                deleteListener.onDeleteSuccess(person);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                deleteListener.onDeleteFailure(error.getMessage());
            }

    });
}
```

And when I load the persons the ones that are deleted seem to have a reference in realm and doesn't seem to be completely removed.

```
@Override
    public void loadPersons(final LoadPersonListener loadPersonListener) {
        if(mRealm.isClosed()) {
            mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }

        RealmResults<Person> personsList = mRealm.where(Person.class).findAll();
        if(personsList.size() > 0) {
            loadPersonListener.onLoadPersonSuccess(personsList);
        }
        else {
            loadPersonListener.onLoadPersonFailure("No items in the database");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should update to 2.1.1, but definitely above 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You aren't removing anything from the Realm at the moment, you're just querying. Also, you're accessing the Person you sent in on a background thread, which ought to throw IllegalStateException.

So instead of

```
@Override
 public void deletePerson(final Person person, final DeleteListener deleteListener) {
    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("mId", person.getId()).findAll();
        }
```

You should have

```
@Override
public void deletePerson(final Person person, final DeleteListener deleteListener) {
    final String id = person.getId();
    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("mId", id).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
        }
```

Comment: I missed that line out as I was trying `remove`. I am actaully using deleteAllFromRealm which doesn't work for me.

Comment: Then the list of elements you are showing in your adapter aren't actually managed by the Realm. You're probably copying things out into an ArrayList or something, instead of using `RealmResults` as you normally should in order to receive automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

Here in you code you only query data asynchronously. For deletion use .remove() method while looping on result of query.
Suppose, that mId is @Primary key, removal will look like:

```
RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("mId", person.getId()).findFirst().removeFromRealm();
```

Comment: I'm using realm.deleteAllFromRealm() I thought that should work. remove is now deprecated.

Comment: `remove()` is deprecated since certain 0.89.0

Comment: Is Person instance you pass into method managed by Realm? maybe this is the case - it points to object inside realm, so db can't remove it

Comment: try passing just id instead of Person object

Comment: Wrong, you can delete managed RealmObject if you are in a transaction using `deleteFromRealm()`. But yes, considering he accesses the id of the object on a background thread, he should definitely only pass the id.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What would be the correct syntax for deleteFromRealm. For the insertion I am doing this  `Person personObject = realm.createObject(Person.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());`

Comment: @ant2009 the correct syntax is in my answer. Your error however is most possibly in your adapter. I would assume it is not a [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), even though it simplifies this issue greatly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce. I am not using a RealmRecylcerViewAdapter. I will change this and see if it works.

Comment: It really depends on how you're initializing your adapter with data